# Logcat formatting inconsistent

Tags: android, logcat

I'm retrieving logcat messages with this code and compiling them to an arraylist (log) below:

```
try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"logcat", "-d"});
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    try {

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
            log.add(line);
            }
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        }
    catch (IOException e) {}
```

When I actually see what is being inserted into the list (by printing 'line'), I get two different things:

Tablet:

```
D/UsbDeviceManager(  208): updateUsbNotification mConnected = true, mConnected = true, mCurrentFunctions = mtp,adb, mUsbNotificationId = 0
```

Phone:

```
06-14 00:45:14.090  1687  3676 D *PJSIP_ANDROID*: Expires: 3600
```

Why does the logcat format differ between the devices? Can I get the tablet outout to look like the phone?

Comment: Are they running the same version of Android?

Comment: Tablet is 4.0.3 the phone is 4.0.4. Another phone I tested it on running 4.1.2 is displaying the same output as the tablet

Comment: My options are: Getting them all to look like 4.0.4 output or how to pull time, level, class, tag, and text regardless of version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting explicit logcat format?

```
  -v <format>     Sets the log print format, where <format> is one of:

              brief process tag thread raw time threadtime long
```

Comment: something like this? the syntax might be incorrect {"logcat -v long *:*"}

Comment: Yes in your case.         process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v long");